# Error debido a que la tabla User ya "existe"

Tags: laravel-5

Me estoy encontrando con un extraño error por el cual cuando intento hacer la migración de la tabla, pero me topo con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me extraña ya que segun eso tengo replicado la tabla User.
Miro en mis directorios y me veo con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En efecto, hay 2 clases User, pero diria que no tiene nada que ver. Fijaos en la otra tabla de User.php:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A que se debera este error?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel trae de "fábrica" una migración para crear la tabla **users** que usará para el sistema de login de usuarios. Si después de instalar el framework creas tu propia migración para crear una tabla **users** y no eliminas la migración original cuando lanzas migraciones se usa una y al tratar de usar la siguiente, como la tabla **users** ya se ha creado tienes el error.

Puedes optar por:

1. Eliminar la migración original si vas a personalizar el sistema de login o no usarlo y añadir la tuya, antes de lanzar las migraciones.
2. Modificar la migración original para ajustarla a tus necesidades, antes de lanzar las migraciones.
3. Lanzar las migraciones primero, y luego crear las tuyas, teniendo en cuenta que la migración para la tabla **users** va a ser para actualizar lo que requieras, no para crearla.

***Nota:*** si ya lanzaste migraciones, puedes eliminar la base de datos y empezar de 0, en otro caso: ya tienes una tabla **users**, comprueba cual es y sigue con la opción 3 si la tabla creada es la original de Laravel o eliminar la migración que trae Laravel si la que se aplicó fue la tuya, para evitar el error al lanzar nuevas migraciones.

Comment: Al quitar mi migración create_users_table se ha solucionado. Observo que variables que cree para esa tabla se han conservado. ¿Cual es ese archivo de migración original para que pueda quitarlo y dejar solo el mio?

Comment: @Miguel Alparez yo tengo un Laravel 5.1 ahora mismo y lo que trae en la carpeta "database/migrations/" son dos ficheros: *xxx_create_users_table.php* y *xxx_create_password_resets_table.php*

Comment: pues ha sido precisamente create_users_table.php el que me da error. Mi versión es la 5.5, por lo que quiza algo ha cambiado. Y si soy sincero, me es esto extraño, porque ha sido reciente cuando me ha saltado el error, al intentar crear una tabla de rol y darle a User una clave foranea a dicha tabla.

Comment: Tambien estoy interesado en lo de eliminar toda la base de datos para empezar de 0. ¿Como hago eso?

Comment: @Miguel Alparez para eliminar la BD en principio desde fuera de laravel, es decir con una aplicación de gestión como mysqladmin, al eliminarla se borra también la tabla donde laravel registra las migraciones realizadas por lo que empiezas de 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo arregle.
Para limpiar por completo una base de datos y se realice correctamente las migraciones, hay que utilizar php ***artisan migrate:fresh***.